# Dynamic Column Range in a Sumif/Sumifs

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

Is it possible to add a dynamic column range in a `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` function?

- `month_1` is the first month a user selects (translated into a number, i.e. Jan = 1).
- `month_2` is the 2nd month a user selects (Feb = 2).

The idea is the `[sum_range]` in the `SUMIF` function would sum the values where the `criteria` is true for the range of column 1 through 2.  I tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> for the below, but it still does not work.  I also tried using `SUM` with `INDEX/MATCH`, but there are multiple rows that could meet the criteria so I need the full "Criteria Range".

`Column E` through `P` are **Jan - Dec** (1 to 12) months. So the idea is that by indexing this full range (or offset), I can sum different ranges of columns together (3 to 5, 4 to 6, etc...)

```
=SUMIF(CONSOLIDATED!$C:$C,$AE72,OFFSET(CONSOLIDATED!D:D,,month_1):OFFSET(CONSOLIDATED!D:D,,month_2))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Below is a formula that *does* work (if I didn't need to use `SUMIF`). This "*modified*" range is where I used a `SUMIF` to calculate on the main sheet:

```
=SUM(INDEX(CONSOLIDATED!$E$494:$P$502,MATCH($AE76,CONSOLIDATED!$D$494:$D$502,0),month_1):INDEX(CONSOLIDATED!$E$494:$P$502,MATCH($AE76,CONSOLIDATED!$D$494:$D$502,0),month_2))
```

Comment: Can you please add an image of your data set?